# Where should I ask this type of question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about algorithms that need to be computationally efficient (optimal would be better).

In particular the tone of the question would be: "I have well-known mathematical problem X, I know generic solution such-and-such (computationally intensive in my case), does a computationally optimal solution/algorithm exists?"

Should I ask on Stack Overflow, Computer Science, Software Engineering, or Math?

Please note that I am not asking for recommendations or suggestions. If a computationally optimal algorithm exists its optimality should have been **proved** in a paper, and is not a matter of opinion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) - [Operations Research](https://or.stackexchange.com/).